# How to get rid of duplicate results in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has some duplicate results. For example:

```
`person_url`    `movie_url`
1                2
1                2
2                3
```

Would become -->

```
`person_url`    `movie_url`
1                2
2                3
```

I know how to do it by creating a new table,

```
create table tmp_credits (select distinct * from name);
```

However, it is a pretty large table and I have a couple indexes on it which will need to be re-created. How would I do this transformation in place, that is, without creating a new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `UNIQUE` index over your table's columns using the `IGNORE` keyword:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE name ADD UNIQUE INDEX (person_url, movie_url);
```

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/alter-table.html):

> `IGNORE` is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how `ALTER TABLE` works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If `IGNORE` is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If `IGNORE` is specified, only the first row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.

This will also prevent duplicates from being added in the future.

Comment: Thanks, and that will delete all the duplicates entries in the existing table?

Comment: @David542: Yes, see the extract from the manual quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just putting a semantic layer/view on top of the table that de-dups?

```
select  person_url, movie_url
from name
group by person_url, movie_url
```

Comment: The question asks how to *remove* duplicate rows, not how to *hide* them.

Answer (score 0):

```
`create table temp
(col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20));
INSERT INTO  temp VALUES
('1','one'),('2','two'),('2','two');
`select col1,col2 from temp
  union 
 select col1,col2 from temp;
```

`